# SSL Certificate not being loaded

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have this in the config page

```
  <IfModule ssl_module>
      SSLEngine On
      SSLCertificateFile /srv/website.com/config/ssl/website_com.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /srv/website.com/config/ssl/server.key
      SSLCertificateChainFile "/srv/website.com/config/ssl/website_com.ca-bundle
    </IfModule>
```

I'm running Debian 9 with Apache mod-ssl.

The config page is apache2.conf in there I have this Include ports.conf

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Uploaded the docs in SSL from Comodo which was a positiveSSL so I had to concatenate the .crt files like this:

```
cat USERTrustRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt >> website_com.cabundle
```

Did a configtest where syntax is ok. Gracefully restarted apache the website.com is still up and working but if I go to https://website.com it says safari can’t access the page.

I’ve tested the connection via https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=website.com which said no secure protocols…

Then checked for errors via

```
openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect example.com:443

    CONNECTED(00000003)
    139742262367488:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong    
version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:
    ---
    no peer certificate available
    ---
    No client certificate CA names sent
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 176 bytes
    Verification: OK
    ---
    New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
    Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
    Compression: NONE
    Expansion: NONE
    No ALPN negotiated
    SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1509040891
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

I understand that the Client Certificate CA names aren't getting sent. I've read this in the default-ssl.conf file

```
#   Certificate Authority (CA):
#   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
#   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
#   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
#   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
#   to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
#   Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
#SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt
```

But is this the same file I'm referencing in the website.conf file above?

I've spoken to my hosting support and registrar support and none of them have a clue how to set this up manually on the terminal...

Also how do I make it default to the https:// connection?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that the chain file extension and the concatenation is incorrect
If you have Windows OS then follow the following steps
1)Double-click on the certificate i.e website_com.crt 
 
2) Now you need to click on certificate path tab (here you will see the chaining of certificates, the top one is the root certificate and the middle one is the intermediate certificate)
 
3) Double-click on the middle one, a new popup will open
4) Now click on details
 5) Click on copy to file.. 
6) Click next >> select **base-64 encoded x.509 (.cer)**>> click **next**>>save the file as abc 
7) Repeat the steps 1) to 
6) but you need to select the top one i.e the root certificate and save the file as xyz 
8) Open the abc via notepad, copy the content and save the content in a new notepad say 123.txt 
11) Similarly, open the xyz via notepad, copy the content and paste it in 123.txt file below the first content.
 
12) Now rename the file from 123.txt to 123.crt

this is the only required change
    SSLCertificateChainFile /srv/website.com/config/ssl/123.crt

Comment: Thank you for this but I use a mac. I've double clicked on the certificate keychain opens it up. But sadly I don't know what I'm looking for when I click on view certificates.

Comment: If this is the intermediate **USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt** and this is the root **AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt** then use the vim command to see the content
Copy the content of **AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt** and paste it below the content of **USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt** then just update the following code `SSLCertificateChainFile /srv/website.com/config/ssl/USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt`

Comment: Else you can concatenate only this two file using 
`cat U USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt >> 123.crt`